# Containing draggable circle to a larger circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry, drag

I am really struggling with this i need to restrain a small circle within the bounds of a larger circle using javascript i have it containing and i am making progress but would really appreciate anyone giving me a hand.

EXAMPLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/z9vqLnsL/1/

$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        start: function () {

```
    },
    drag: function (evt) {
        console.log(evt);
        var D = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(($('#containment-wrapper').width() / 2) - evt.clientX, 2) + Math.pow(($('#containment-wrapper').width() / 2) - evt.clientY, 2));
        if (D <= ($('#containment-wrapper').width() / 2)) {
            $('#check').html('inside');
        } else {
            $('#check').html('outside');
            $("#draggable").left(x_last);
            $("#draggable").right(y_last);
        }
    },
    stop: function () {

    }
});
```

});

I have tried setting the circle to the last x and y values if the circle is dragged outside but it is just really jumpy and doesn't not work smoothly.

Any help please?

UPDATE: By doing the above i managed to keep the circle inbounds but it stops the drag motion.

Comment: I'm not good with math, but I think you need to calculate the furthest `x` and `y` position from the center of large circle to the current pointer position (if it's outside), then change the `x_last` and `y_last` to the calculated value rather then to the last `x` and `y` so it should be more fluid

Comment: Hi Kyojimaru, thanks for the response i am also not very good with math but i will give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to limit the distance of the small circle's coordinates from the origin, here being the center of the big circle:

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        drag: function (e, ui) {
            var r = $('#containment-wrapper').width()/2;
            var small_r = $('#draggable').width()/2;
            var origin_x = r - small_r;
            var origin_y = r - small_r;
            var x = ui.position.left - origin_x, y = ui.position.top - origin_y;
            var l = Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y);
            var l_in = Math.min(r - small_r, l);
            ui.position = {'left': x/l*l_in + origin_x, 'top': y/l*l_in + origin_y};
        },
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdb3geob/).

btw, this isn't super-flexible, if the big circle needs to be changed to an arbitrary shape, handling arbitrary cases well is quite complicated.

Comment: Hi simonzack really appreciate the response this works great for me i did make some progress you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/z9vqLnsL/2/

Comment: @user1503606 I think you're thinking the right way, but it's a bit easier to consider the center of the large circle as the origin, instead of doing distances. btw, Glad I helped, you can accept the answer if it works.